# Substring of a file name in ADF

Tags: azure, substring, pipeline, azure-data-factory

in Azure Data factory ,i am getting "Common_EUR_AP_COMPCODE_YYY_MM_DD"  as file name from "Get Metadata" activity which is then going thru "foreach loop" , now i want to take just "COMPCODE"  bit of it inside foreach > "set variable" and ignore the rest. Can somebody please help on how to do it.

i used many ways but the v close one was "@substring(item().name,add(indexof(item().name,'*'),3),add(lastindexof(item().name,'*'),1))"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this expression:

```
@split(item().name,'_')[3]
```

Result:
[image]

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#split

Comment: If you think my answer help you, you could mark it as answer. Thanks a lot.